# Setting BlobAccessTier while generating upload SAS Url

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Description: Setting BlobAccessTier while generating upload SAS Url.

We are uploading data to an Azure storage account using a SAS URL having write permissions. We would like to upload these blobs with AccessTier as Cold, though the default Storage Account one is Hot. Is there a way to specify the AccessTier while generating an upload SAS Url?

Many thanks in advance.

Technologies: spring-boot, azure, kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about the ability to specify the access tier in the SAS token so that the blob is uploaded directly in that tier, then the answer is no. SAS token does not have a parameter which can control that.

When you are uploading the blob using the SAS URL, in order to upload blob directly into the `Cold` tier, you would need to include `x-ms-access-tier` in the request headers and set its value to `Cold`. If you are using any Blob Storage SDKs, then please look at the documentation for them. You will find a parameter which allows you to specify the access tier while uploading blobs using the SDK.

Comment: Thanks have tried this out and works well. But I'm looking to set this at the service level while generating the SAS Url and not while uploading. Please let me know, if there's such options. I'm looking into SDK reference for these.

Comment: `Thanks have tried this out and works well. But I'm looking to set this at the service level while generating the SAS Url and not while uploading. Please let me know, if there's such options` - Unfortunately no. You do not get to set/restrict the access tier while creating a SAS (just like you do not get to set/restrict the blob type).